# How can I transfer data by excluding files over 100MB but including files that are over 100MB if they match a pattern of known file extensions?

Tags: files, rsync, file-transfer

How can I transfer data by excluding files over 100MB but including files that are over 100MB if they match a pattern of known file extensions?

I've read through rsync options and I don't think I can achieve this with rsync, because `--max-size=` is not flexible like this, even in combination with `--include` or `--exclude`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two steps (for simplicity, even though these steps can definitely be combined).

First transfer "small" files:

```
find /source/path -type f -size -100M -print0 |
rsync -av -0 --files-from=- / user@server:/destination/
```

Then transfer "big" files whose filenames match `pattern`:

```
find /source/path -type f -size +99M -name 'pattern' -print0 |
rsync -av -0 --files-from=- / user@server:/destination/
```

This is, however, untested.

`-print0` in GNU `find` (and others) will print the found names with a `nul` delimiter, and `-0` with `rsync` will make `--files-from-` interpret this standard input stream in that particular way.

The file paths read with `--files-from` should be relative to the specified source, that's why I use `/` as the source in `rsync` (I'm assuming `/source/path` in `find` is an absolute path).

---

Combined variation (also not tested):

```
find /source/path -type f \
    \( -size -100M -o -name 'pattern' \) -print0 |
rsync -av -0 --files-from=- / user@server:/destination/
```

With more than one allowable `pattern` string for "big" files:

```
find /source/path -type f \
    \( -size -100M -o -name 'pattern1' -o -name 'pattern2' -o -name 'pattern3' \) -print0 |
rsync -av -0 --files-from=- / user@server:/destination/
```

Each `pattern` may be something like `*.mp4` or whatever file extensions you use.  Note that these needs to be quoted, as in `-name '*.mp4'`.

Comment: I'm not too sure why you have used `\(` and `\)` inbetween the `-size` and final pattern, but it works with and without? Anyway, this example is still picking up files that do not match the pattern.

Comment: @adampski Are you referring to my last example?  That would trigger for files of size less than 100 Mb, _or_ for file whose names matches any of the patterns. The `\( ... \)` groups the conditional so that  `-print0` happens for any file that matches any of the conditions.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I noticed it was still `-100M` so I assumed this was a mistake and made it `+99M`. However, the "or" in your response is the key bit of information that enables me to understand that it's copying all files less than 100M or files that match the pattern. Thank you!